# How to make a new copy of table without CREATE TABLE but using INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and trying to figure out some not trivia task.

I have a table `PROPERTY` and need to copy some of the data to absolutely new table `PROPERTY_1` (`PROPERTY_1` is not created and I'm not allowed to use `CREATE TABLE`). I have to use `INSERT` only!

I've googled some fancy commands like `INSERT INTO` from MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO PROPERTY_1 SELECT * FROM PROPERTY
```

but it's no help because (surprise-surprise!) `PROPERTY_1` is not created.

Is it any possible way to pass this task or it's just some kind of weird task?

Comment: You can't create a table with `INSERT`. `INSERT` requires that the table already exists. If you don't want to `CREATE` the table separately you want [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Why do you "need" to copy data from one table to another?

Comment: Because that's what is written in task. Thats why I "need" to copy

Comment: Copying data from one table to another will cause data redundancy, and typically lead to data inconsistency. Can't you just create a view instead?

Comment: That looks like a perfect advice. Lets make VIEW

Comment: Use `SELECT * into <newtable> from <oldtable>`

Comment: If this a class assignment and you are required to use `INSERT INTO ` instead of `SELECT INTO` then one of the following is happening: 1) The assignment is flawed 2) You're not supposed to be using MS SQL Server. But @jarlh's advice is also sound - simply copying a table within a database is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [Select Into](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) as described in the Microsoft: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That would be super-easy. The task is clear - use INSERT. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select into` to create the structure only and use `Insert into` to copy the data like below:

```
SELECT * INTO PROPERTY_1 FROM PROPERTY WHERE 1=0

INSERT INTO PROPERTY_1 SELECT * FROM PROPERTY
```

Benefits of using `Select into` to create the structure of the copy table:

You don't need to worry about the columns and their data types in the new table (PROPERTY_1) as those will be similar to the base table (PROPERTY). The new table schema will match the original schema, including identity columns.

There won't be any errors while inserting the records in the new table.

Comment: If you're going to recommend doing it that way, you should explain what the advantage is.

Comment: @JeffModen Thanks for the suggestions. I have added some benefits of using 'select into' in the answer as well.